# proper way to ask for permission to change TV channels

Tags: expressions

If you want to change your TV channel to another one, would you say, "Can I change the channel?" or "Can I change channels?" or anything else?

Comment: Using "can I" rather than "may I" when requesting permission is considered rude by many people.

Comment: Only pedants care if you say "can I" rather than "may I".  It is fully incorporated into oral language.

Comment: This would not be different from any other sort of request, and there are probably hundreds of different ways to formulate it. I lean to something like *Would you mind if we changed channels?* or even simply *Are you watching this?*

Comment: "Is it okay [with you] if I change the channel?"

Answer (score 3):

If you're negotiating with others who are watching to TV, other options would be—

> May I change the channel?

That's slightly more polite than "can I".

> Would you mind if I changed the channel?

That's even more polite, acknowledging that others might be a bit attached to the current program.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could informally say something like this:

> Are you watching this? Do you mind if I change the channel?

I think it's also possible to use "Can I...?" as you posted in your question.

Comment: I think it's also possible to use "can I ...." as you posted in your question